# return pointer to MSG with exported member function - DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Here is a reproducing example

```
// in a header from a dll

class Window{
public:
MSG _declspec(dllexport) *getMessage(); //compiles
MSG* _declspec(dllexport) getMessage(); //fails
}
```

Definitions are set in a .cpp file.

In the Application, I cant access the Member function, why ? I am access the function of course from a instance of Window like:

```
Window App;
func_with_parameters(param,App.getMessage(),0,0); // not found !
```

Comment: For the latter question, the default visibility of a `class` block is `private`.

Comment: Sry, forgot to add that in the question. In the code, it is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first off.

```
    __declspec(dllexport) MSG* GetMessage();
```

Is the proper way the function definition should be.

Secondly, the `__declspec(dllexport)` will need to be `__declspec(dllimport)` in the header file of the project that consumes the dll or it will not import. That is usually handled via macros such as this.

```
    #ifdef _WINDLL // Defined by Visual Studio when building a Dll
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else 
    #define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
```

Third, it may be better to export at the class level instead of the function level e.g.

```
    class __declspec(dllexport) Window
```

or with the macro

```
    class DLL_API Window
```